# Redirect url to url to www

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, redirect, configuration

I have a problem with redirect url to url in nginx:

for example I have a link:

https://example.com/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty?OfferID=124296

working function:

```
location  ^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty(.*)$  {
return 301 https://example.com/oferty-specjalne/; }
```

not working functions:

```
location ~ ^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty\?OfferID=(124170|124296|124299|123483|63788|97002)$  {
return 301 https://example.com/oferty-specjalne/; }

location ~ ^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty?OfferID=(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://example.com/oferty-specjalne/$1; }

location  ^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty?OfferID=97002 {
return 301 https://example.com/oferty-specjalne/; }
```

I checked the regexes in the testers and everything is ok.
I am asking for information where I am making a mistake and how I can solve it, or maybe for example.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but just in case it gives you problems: you have "domainame" in one of the returns instead of "domainname".

Comment: Just the domain does not matter, because it's been exchanged anyway, it's just an example.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. In the future, use example.com. That is why IANA reserves it.

Comment: Thank you for attention, I will remember :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the URI following the `?` is the query string (or arguments) and is not part of the normalised URI used by the `location` and `rewrite` directives - so your rules will never match. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

If you have complex regular expressions that need to match against the entire URI (including the query string) you need to use the `$request_uri` variable. This can be tested using an `if` or a `map`. With more than a few regular expressions, a `map` is the preferred solution.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    ~^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty\?OfferID=(124170|124296|124299|123483|63788|97002)$
                                                                  /oferty-specjalne/;
    ~^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty\?OfferID=(?<offerid>.*)$ /oferty-specjalne/$offerid;
    ~^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty\?OfferID=97002           /oferty-specjalne/;
    ~^/oferty-specjalne/szczegoly-oferty                          /oferty-specjalne/;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
```

Regular expressions are evaluated in order until a matching rule is found, so order the rules with most specific first and least specific last.
Use named captures, as the numeric captures can go out of scope.
You do not need to specify the scheme or domain name if they are the same.
The `map` directive sits outside of the `server block. 
See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.